# Is there a situation where ここの can be shortened / changed to この?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Context: Someone in a group that I’m following asked a what the この in the following sentence stands for:

“わたしはゼルダ。このハイラルの王女。”

I was thinking: can’t it be possible that the この here essentially means the same thing as ここの.  So the latter one just got changed into the first? A possible reason for the change might be the lack of space, as you can see on the screenshot I provided along with this post.

So in short: is it possible for ここの to be changed into この given the right circumstances?

[Screenshot taken from the game the person was playing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axKPa.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

ここの can't change to この. We commonly say この+noun for "this+a noun", so we say このハイラル for "this ハイラル". For example, we say この国 for a word "this country", not ここの国.

In addition, ここの can mean "belong here". For example, この料理 means "this dish", ここの料理 means "dishes that belong to this restaurant", that is この店の料理(dishes of this restaurant).

Answer (score 2):

I think in this context, the meaning of この is that of a simple "this", but for emphasis.

> わたしはゼルダ。**この**ハイラルの王女。
>   I am Zelda. Princess of **this** (kingdom of) Hyrule.

Do note that there is no pronunciation emphasis, I've just highlighted where this fits.